# automatically change geometry with KOMA-pagestyles

Tags: koma-script, geometry, scrlayer-scrpage, pagestyle

I'm trying to change the geometry (namely the top/head height) automatically depending on the selected pagestyle.

The goal is to have a bigger backgroundpicture in the header for every new chapter. Like for example: the eyes of the tiger in regular headers and the whole head in headers with a new chapter on the page. (For the pictures I'm using layers.)

I'm using the KOMA-package scrlayer-scrpage to add the geometry to the pagestyle-pair. I puzzled this together reading the KOMA-documentation, although I have to add I did'nt read the whole thing.

The result though is that the geometry defined last is kept globaly and the text is shifted downward (even out of the page) if a geometry with bigger top-value is called:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{scrreprt}
\KOMAoptions{titlepage=false,twoside, headinclude=false}

% multiple columns with the multicols-environment
\usepackage{multicol}

% language-settings similar to babel
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[spelling=new]{german}

% type area and margins
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\geometry{left=3cm,right=2.5cm,top=10cm,head=5cm,bottom=3.75cm}
\savegeometry{plaingeometry}
\geometry{left=3cm,right=2.5cm,top=3.5cm,bottom=3.75cm}
\savegeometry{scrheadingsgeometry} 

% KOMA pagestyles
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
% should call \loadgeometry every time scrheadings is selected
\AddToLayerPageStyleOptions{scrheadings}{onselect={\loadgeometry{scrheadingsgeometry}}}
% should call \loadgeometry every time plain.scrheadings is selected, eg. with a new chapter
\AddToLayerPageStyleOptions{plain.scrheadings}{onselect=\loadgeometry{plaingeometry}}

% set headmarks
\automark[section]{chapter}

% testing
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}

    \chapter{Chapter}
    \section{Section}
    \lipsum[1]
    \subsection{{Subsection}}
    \lipsum[2-4]

    \subsubsection{Subsubsection}
    \lipsum[5-11]

    \chapter{And back again}
    \lipsum[12-17]


\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Either if you know a way to fix this, or to change geometry synchronised with changes of pagestyle I would appreciate it.(Maybe a change every time \chapter ist called would suffice to, but seems a bit to ugly to me.)

PS: First time I switched from reading to writing in this really helpfull community. I hope my autodidactic aproach doesn't hurt to bad.

Comment: You shouldn't do this. If you want this on chapter pages it is quite enough to move the chapter text down but leave the geometry unchanged.

Comment: thanks for your fast reply.

Comment: I assume youe had something in the lines of '\newcommand{\mychapter}[1]{\par \vspace*{3cm} \chapter{#1}}' in mind.

Comment: The KOMA-classes have better tools to change the spacing before a chapter.

Comment: Just out of curiosity (and to better understand the KOMA-layers): Why shouldn't I do this. Besides the point, that it obviously does not work ;-)

Comment: wrong timing. pagestyle are often set on a page, while geometry must normally be set before the page. Beside this changes of the geometry are suspicious anyway. You need them seldom.

Comment: Moreover if you select a page style locally, e.g., `\pagestyle{first} several pages {\pagestyle{second} several more pages} several pages again`, the page style outside the group won't be set explicitly again at the end of the group. The local page style just becomes invalid and this switches back to the previous page style without selecting it. Similar if `\thispagestyle` is used.

Comment: I would recommend to use `\RedeclareSectionCommand` to move the chapter title down. Then you can either use a layer to add the background picture or `\setchapterpreamble`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like  Ulrike Fischer and Schweinebacke suggested I used KOMA functionality like \RedeclareSectionCommand to achive more or less, what I wanted.

Thanks for your advice, it helped me to get the bigger picture.

Thats what I've done with the picturestuff left out.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{scrreprt}
\KOMAoptions{titlepage=false,twoside, headinclude=false, twocolumn}

% language-settings similar to babel
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[spelling=new]{german}

% type area and margins
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\geometry{left=3cm,right=2.5cm,top=3.5cm,bottom=3.75cm}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[%
    beforeskip = -2.5cm plus 2mm minus 1mm,%
    afterskip  = 2.5cm plus 1mm minus 1mm%
    ]{chapter}

% KOMA pagestyles
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}

% set headmarks
\automark[section]{chapter}

% testing
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{Chapter}
    \section{Section}
    \lipsum[1]
    \subsection{{Subsection}}
    \lipsum[2-4]

    \subsubsection{Subsubsection}
    \lipsum[5-11]

    \chapter{And back again}
    \lipsum[12-17]

\end{document}
```

What exactly each of the lengths in

`\RedeclareSectionCommand[%
    beforeskip = -2.5cm plus 2mm minus 1mm,%
    afterskip  = 2.5cm plus 1mm minus 1mm%
    ]{chapter}`

does, keeps slipping my mind though.